# Best Practices when working on Database: E-commerce website

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, e-commerce

Currently I'm developing an E-commerce website and I have some doubts in creating the tables on the main Database.

The website has 2 types of users: Buyers and Sellers. When a user buys something that other user published, the primary key of the "Item" is referenced buy the table "Transactions". The thing is, what happens if the user that published that Item edits the item? Then the user that bought the item would see the item edited and this should not happen.

Should I create another table to store permanently the original data of the item purchased? 
Is there any standard procedure to do this?
Currently im working with MySQL. Would this be scalable when the website grows?

Sorry for my bad english and ty for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction table should contain the details of the transaction like BuyerName, SellerName, ItemID, ItemVersion, Cost, Quantity, etc. In the Items table create a column 'Version'. Any Edits to the item should be inserted as a new version instead of an edit. This would keep all your past data.